# IndentationError: expected an indented block error de noob

Tags: python

Estoy empezando en la programación y me figura este error me pueden ayudar a identificarlo por favor.

```
usuarios = {"Marta","David","Elvira","Juan","Marcos"}
administradores = {"Juan","Marta"}

print ("estos son los usuarios: ",usuarios,)
print ("estos son los adm: ", administradores,"\n")

x = input ("introduzca un nombre para crear en usuarios: ")
usuarios.add(x)


print ("""Menu de usuarios, que desea hacer: 
1) Quiere que sea ADM
2) Solo quiere que sea Usuario
3) Eliminar un ADM
4) salir""")

while (True):

option = input()

if option == '1':

    administradores.add(x)
    print ("El grupo adm ahora son: ", administradores,"\n")

    print ("""¿Desea comprobar?: 
    1) Si
    2) No""")

    while (True):
        option2 = input()
        if option2 == '1':
            for x in usuarios:
                if x in administradores:
                     print (usuarios, "es adm")                

                else:
                    print (usuarios, "no es adm")

        elif opcion2 == '2':
            break
        else:
            "Debes introducir una opcion valida"

elif option == '2':
    print ("el grupo usuarios son: ", usuarios,"\n")

    print ("""¿Desea comprobar?: 
    1) Si
    2) No""")

    while (True):
        option3 = input()
        if option3 == '1':
            for x in usuarios:
                if x in administradores:
                     print (usuarios, "es adm")                

                else:
                    print (usuarios, "no es adm")

        elif opcion3 == '2':
            break
        else:
            "Debes introducir una opcion valida"

elif option == '3':

    print ("Estos son los Adm: ",administradores,"\n","Estos son los Usuarios: ",usuarios,"\n")

    y = input ("ponga un nombre para eliminar de adm: ")
    administradores.discard(y)
    while (True):  

    if y in usuarios:
        print ("el grupo administradores es: ", administradores,"\n")
        break
    else:
        print ("nombre introducido no esta en los usuarios.")

elif option == '4':
    print("¡Hasta luego! Ha sido un placer ayudarte")
        break
else:
    print ("Elige un comando valido")
```

Comment: En que línea te sale el mensaje?

Answer (score 0):

En Python a diferencia de otros lenguajes de programación la indentación es parte de la sintaxis del lenguaje. Asegúrate que estas agregando la indentación en el lugar correcto. Un buen editor debería ayudarte con esta tarea.

En tu caso:

Todo el código desde después del primer `while (True):` debe ser indentado

```
while (True):

    option = input()

    if option == '1':
    ... # Muchas lineas después
    else:
        print ("Elige un comando valido")
```

Luego el bloque dentro del último `while (True):` también deber ser indentado un nivel más

```
while (True):  

    if y in usuarios:
        print ("el grupo administradores es: ", administradores,"\n")
        break
    else:
        print ("nombre introducido no esta en los usuarios.")
```

Y finalmente el `break` de casi al final debe retroceder un nivel

```
elif option == '4':
    print("¡Hasta luego! Ha sido un placer ayudarte")
    break
```

#### El código completo a continuación:

```
usuarios = {"Marta","David","Elvira","Juan","Marcos"}
administradores = {"Juan","Marta"}

print ("estos son los usuarios: ",usuarios,)
print ("estos son los adm: ", administradores,"\n")

x = input ("introduzca un nombre para crear en usuarios: ")
usuarios.add(x)


print ("""Menu de usuarios, que desea hacer: 
1) Quiere que sea ADM
2) Solo quiere que sea Usuario
3) Eliminar un ADM
4) salir""")

while (True):

    option = input()

    if option == '1':

        administradores.add(x)
        print ("El grupo adm ahora son: ", administradores,"\n")

        print ("""¿Desea comprobar?: 
        1) Si
        2) No""")

        while (True):
            option2 = input()
            if option2 == '1':
                for x in usuarios:
                    if x in administradores:
                         print (usuarios, "es adm")                

                    else:
                        print (usuarios, "no es adm")

            elif opcion2 == '2':
                break
            else:
                "Debes introducir una opcion valida"

    elif option == '2':
        print ("el grupo usuarios son: ", usuarios,"\n")

        print ("""¿Desea comprobar?: 
        1) Si
        2) No""")

        while (True):
            option3 = input()
            if option3 == '1':
                for x in usuarios:
                    if x in administradores:
                         print (usuarios, "es adm")                

                    else:
                        print (usuarios, "no es adm")

            elif opcion3 == '2':
                break
            else:
                "Debes introducir una opcion valida"

    elif option == '3':

        print ("Estos son los Adm: ",administradores,"\n","Estos son los Usuarios: ",usuarios,"\n")

        y = input ("ponga un nombre para eliminar de adm: ")
        administradores.discard(y)
        while (True):  

            if y in usuarios:
                print ("el grupo administradores es: ", administradores,"\n")
                break
            else:
                print ("nombre introducido no esta en los usuarios.")

    elif option == '4':
        print("¡Hasta luego! Ha sido un placer ayudarte")
        break
    else:
        print ("Elige un comando valido")
```